# After upgrading .NET framework 4.8 ( update KB4486105 ) Service Bus Gateway stuck in starting mode

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

After upgrading .NET framework 4.8 on windows server 2012 R2, Service Bus Gateway stuck in starting mode.

- Machine : windows server 2012 R2
- .NET Framework version : 4.8 (windows update KB4486105)
- Service bus version : 1.1

is there any patch or prerequisite needed to be installed for Service bus 1.1 to work with.NET framework 4.8
Any other solution to issue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a fix for this now, download this Update for Service Bus Server 1.1 (KB3086798) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49496